# Kerberos keytab to service authorization of all AD users

Tags: windows, active-directory, kerberos, keytab

Say I have keytab file generated for a service to someUserAccount. Also I have an SPN registered to someUserAccount. I want to authorize to the service i.e. get ticket from KDC for any user of AD only with username and without password. Is that possible in my scenario or at all using Kerberos?

Comment: You don't get the ticket from the KDC - the _user_ goes and acquires the ticket from the KDC which it then passes to you

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, OK, is that possible that any AD user goes and acquires the ticket from the KDC without password using keytab file?

Comment: @Maksidrom - Kerberos is SSO.  So users would not need to enter their passwords in this case.  The keytab decrypts the inbound service token to the service which is what allow that service to "tell" who the user is.

Comment: @T-Heron, Is that correct that users will have to be initially authenticated to be able to authorize with Kerberos without password?

Comment: Yes.  You go into work and logon to your computer assuming you are in an AD domain.  Then you go to a Kerberos-protected resource.  That either accepts your or rejects you but will not ask for your password if the application is configured right.